# Is it possible to use OR on a where clause in XQuery?

Tags: xml, database, xpath, xquery, basex

I need to return the title of books and journals where "John Doe" is the author, but my xml file is set up as:

```
<library>
<book>...</book>
<article>...</article>
</library>
```

There are 6 books and journals in total.

I know that if this was SQL I could do something like:

```
SELECT title
FROM library
WHERE bookauthor = "John Doe" OR articleauthor = "John Doe"
```

(*that database wouldn't be normalised but I'm trying to show that I think I know what I need to do, just not sure how with XQuery*)

I tried the following and it returned all 6 titles to me:

```
for $x in doc("xmldata.xml")/library
let $a := $x/article
let $b := $x/book
return ($a/title, $b/title)
```

But I am not sure what to do with the where clause. Similarly I tried the following and got stuck at the same point:

```
for $x in doc("xmldata.xml")/library
return ($x/article/title, $x/book/title)
```

When I attempt to add in a where clause it still returns all 6 entries even though it should only return 1 book and 1 article:

```
for $x in doc("xmldata.xml")/library
where $x/article/author = 'John Doe' 
where $x/book/author = 'John Doe'
return ($x/article/title, $x/book/title)
```

Is anyone able to help me out please? Maybe by pointing me in the right direction or pointing out where I'm going wrong.

Full XML file:

```
<library>
 <book>
  <author>John Doe</author>
  <title>Turnitin</title>
 </book>
 <article>
  <author>John Doe</author>
  <title>Evaluating</title>
 </article>
 <article>
  <author>Shannon, L.</author>
  <title>Reconceptualising</title>
 </article>
 <book>
  <author>Burden, David</author>
  <title>An evaluation</title>
 </book>
 <article>
  <author>Moscrop, C.</author>
  <title>Evaluating a systematic method</title>
 </article>
 <book>
  <author>Beaumont, C.</author>
  <title>Beyond e-learning</title>
 </book>
</library>
```

Comment: Can you post a larger sample of the source XML? I don't see anything wrong with your last query.

Comment: I have added the source XML to the bottom of the post now, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I missed the paths you were querying. There is only one library element, so your `for` loop only iterated once, and then since *at least one* `<author>` matched your `where` clause, it returned all the values from `<library>`.

The solution is to iterate one level down in the hierarchy:

```
for $x in doc("xmldata.xml")/library/*
where $x/author = 'John Doe' 
return $x/title
```

Or if you want to be very clear in which elements you select:

```
for $x in doc("xmldata.xml")/library/(article|book)
...
```

To control output of values for different elements you can use different XPath in your return:

```
...
return ($x/self::book/title, $x/self::article/author)
```

Comment: Hi not sure I understand your reply? :) are you saying I have made a mistake in my query? I want to return the title when library/article/author = "John Doe" OR when library/book/author = "John Doe"

Comment: sorry I replied too soon! it only said "Sorry, I missed the paths you were querying." That works great, thanks! the explanation is helpful too

Comment: Hi sorry there's one other thing I want to do, which is to return the author for articles and the title for books. if I add author into the return it still returns the title. is there any way around that?

Comment: amazing! thanks that makes sense now, will double up on "self" knowledge. One last thing which I am just curious about - is it possible in XQuery to have it so that it returned data where the author is "John Doe" OR "Jane Doe" - using | doesn't seem to work, or OR

Comment: @user2633709 I'm not sure if this is what you're asking but if you use an expression like `$x/author = ('Author 1', 'Author 2')`, it will return true if *any* item in the sequence matches.

Comment: ah it was, I thought it might be an "in" operator but couldn't get the syntax. thank you for all your help on this - is there any recommended resources for xquery? i can only seem to find some on xml and then they say "oh this is xquery but we won't cover that..."

Comment: @user2633709 For "classic" XQuery take a look at Priscilla Walmsley's XQuery book. However, every XQuery database has their own implementation-specific functions and design constraints, so I would also recommend reading BaseX's developer documentation (if that's what you will be using) once you feel good about XQuery in general.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the wildcard `*` to match elements regardless of their name:

```
doc("xmldata.xml")/library/*[author = 'John Doe']/title
```

this is equivalent to the more verbose FLWOR expression

```
for $entry in doc("xmldata.xml")/library/*
where $entry/author = 'John Doe'
return $entry/title
```

Comment: Hi sorry there's one other thing I want to do, which is to return the author for articles and the title for books. if I add author into the return it still returns the title. is there any way around that?

Comment: There are many ways to do this; try this for example: `let $lib := doc("xmldata.xml")/library return ($lib/article[author = 'John Doe']/author, $lib/book[author = 'John Doe']/title)`. For further questions, better open a new StackOverflow entry.